# SISGEV error despite allocating memory on heap? (generating primes)

Tags: c++, debugging, primes

I have written code to generate prime numbers in a range *(using a modified Sieve of Eratosthenes)* , as competitive programming. The code works fine on my Visual Studio, but gives a SISGEV on the website. I use this,

```
static bool *prime = new bool[1000000001];
```

to declare memory. And can not understand the reason behind the SISGEV.

Below is the function, whose parameters are `the lower limit m`, and `the upper limit n`. 
Elements of index `>m` *which are not prime* are marked **false.**

```
static bool *prime = new bool[1000000009]; 
    void SieveOfEratosthenes(int m, int n)
    {
        // Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize
        // all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will
        // finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true.


        memset(prime, true, n + 11);

        int m2;
        if (m > 10) {
            m2 = m / 10; 
            m2 = m2 * 10; 
            m2 = (2 * m2) / 5; 
        }
        else
            m2 = 4;

        prime[1] = false;
        prime[2] = true;
        prime[3] = true;
        prime[5] = true;

        for (int i = m2; i <= n; i += 2) {

            if ( (5*2)/2 >= n) break;

            prime[i] = false; 
            prime[(3 * i) / 2] = false;
            prime[(5 * i) / 2] = false;
        }

        int m3;
        m3 = m % 7;
        m3 = m - m3;

        for (int p = 7; (p)*(p) <= n; p += 6) {

            // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime

            if (prime[p] == true) {

                // Update all multiples of p,

                for (int i = p; i <= n; i += p) {

                    prime[m3+i] = false; //cout << i << " ";
                    if (prime[m3 + p+ 4])  prime[((p+4)*i)/p] = false; 
                    if (prime[m3 + p + 6]) prime[((p+6)*i)/p] = false;
                }
            }
            prime[7] = true;
            prime[11] = true;
            prime[13] = true;
        }

        // Print all prime numbers
        for (int p = m; p <= n; p++)
            if (prime[p])
                cout << p << endl;


    }

int main() {
    //other code
    delete[] prime;
}
```

Comment: So allocating a fixed size array while you get the size parameter passed in, really didn't ring any bells when reading the code before just copy pasting everything to SO?

Comment: Initialization of `prime` (namely `new`) happens only once during execution of the program, `delete[]` is invoked every time the function is called.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Good catch.  I never even noticed it was static.

Comment: @Pixelchemist Thank you. Could you explain to me how to fix that?

Comment: The website allows about 1.5 GBs

Comment: I am now using delete[] in the main, still SISGEV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your pointer is a static variable. In C++ the initialization of a static variable happens only once. The `delete[]` statement however, is executed for every function call.
2. Do not tilt at windmills and use `std::vector` instead of rolling a raw-memory solution.

A simple implementation using `std::vector`: (Adding the extended functionality is left as an exercise to the reader.)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::size_t> eratosthenes(std::size_t const n)
{
  std::vector<bool> A(n, true);
  std::vector<std::size_t> r;
  auto const limit = static_cast<std::size_t>(
    std::ceil(std::sqrt(static_cast<double>(n))));
  // check all numbers up to sqrt(n)
  for (std::size_t i = 2; i <= limit; ++i)
  { 
    // if i is prime, 
    if (A[i])
    {
      // i is prime, put it into return vector
      r.push_back(i);
      // set all multiples of i (below n) to false
      for (std::size_t j = i*i; j < n; j+=i)
      {
        A[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  // fill rest of the primes > sqrt(n) into r
  if (!r.empty())
  {
    for (auto i = limit+1u; i < n; ++i)
    {
      if (A[i]) r.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Printing it:

```
int main()
{
  for (auto v : eratosthenes(120))
  {
    std::cout << v << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```